# Multiple Select Distinct Queries Outputting to a csv File

Tags: postgresql, csv, distinct

I have a table that has about 200 attributes. For each attribute I would like to know all of the possible values. Most attributes have between 2 and 20 possible values.

If the attribute is likely to have far too many different values (e.g. postcode) then I would just like to know the count. (Please note that this doesn't need to be a distinct count, I am more putting the count step in as a placeholder so I maintain the attribute order from the source table than anything else.)

I would like to save this to output to a csv file, although a different output filetype would be acceptable if it is required to hold multiple values for a single attribute.

A shortened and simplified query of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
COPY(
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM complete_file_301115) AS id,
(SELECT DISTINCT (title) FROM complete_file_301115) AS title,
(SELECT COUNT(firstname) FROM complete_file_301115) AS firstname,
(SELECT COUNT(lastname) FROM complete_file_301115) AS lastname,
(SELECT COUNT(address1) FROM complete_file_301115) AS address1,
(SELECT COUNT(address2) FROM complete_file_301115) AS address2,
(SELECT DISTINCT (city) FROM complete_file_301115) AS city,
(SELECT DISTINCT (county) FROM complete_file_301115) AS county,
(SELECT COUNT(postcode) FROM complete_file_301115) AS postcode,
(SELECT DISTINCT (gender) FROM complete_file_301115) AS gender,
(SELECT DISTINCT (job) FROM complete_file_301115) AS job,
(SELECT DISTINCT (children) FROM complete_file_301115) AS children) TO
'/Users/Shared/test123.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER, ENCODING LATIN1);
```

When I run my query, Postgres gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I understand that this error is basically saying that I can't write multiple values for a single attribute in a csv.

My question is is there anyway to save an output file that holds **ALL possible values for each attribute** e.g.

id: 1,2,3,4
title: Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms, Dr  etc.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert this to text. Does it fit to you?

```
 ...
 (array_to_string( array(SELECT DISTINCT (city) FROM complete_file_301115), ',') ) AS city,
 ...
```